# Collada Interface in Java

Tags: java, jogl, collada

I am looking for a *library* to handle `collada` file in `Java` so that I can read **mesh data** and *render* it in my own `jogl` display.

Is there any *already* library *existing* in `Java`?

Answer (score 2):

Did you had a look here : http://code.google.com/p/jaxb-collada/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Not tried this myself, but you should be able to borrow and re-purpose the open source COLLADA importer from [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/):

http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/doc/com/jmex/model/collada/ColladaImporter.html

Comment: I tried this ColladaImporter but I cannot make it works. It needs to install other library such as lwjgl which is a native library. I would like to avoid linking to lwjgl as I am already using jogl.

Comment: I finally make it compile and run but when I use `ColladaImporter.load(input, "model");` I get the following error: `java.lang.NullPointerException com.jmex.model.collada.ColladaImporter.processLambert(ColladaImporter.java:2392)`